# Show immediately ringing call, when data-only push notification is received [ANDROID]

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-callkeep in order to manage calls. I have the problem, that the native ringing call does not happen, when I get a data-only background push notification. I want it to be like in WhatsApp for example, where the phone start immediately ringing.

Is there something else what I have to consider?

Here is the code that listens to the background-message of firebase:

```js
const options = {
   android: {
      alertTitle: permissionRequiredTx,
      alertDescription: permissionDescriptionTx,
      cancelButton: cancelTx,
      okButton: okTx,
      imageName: "samwin_white",
      selfManaged: false,
      additionalPermissions: [],
      // Required to get audio in background when using Android 11
      foregroundService: {
        channelId: CONSTANTS.PACKAGE,
        channelName: foregroundServiceChannelNameTx,
        notificationTitle: foregroundServiceNotificationTitleTx,
      }
   }
}

export const FcmBackgroundHandler = async (remoteMessage: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage) => {
  const { skill, type } = remoteMessage.data;

  try {
    RNCallKeep.registerPhoneAccount({ ...options });
    RNCallKeep.registerAndroidEvents();
    RNCallKeep.setAvailable(true);
    RNCallKeep.canMakeMultipleCalls(false);
   
    RNCallKeep.addEventListener("answerCall", onAnswerCall);
    RNCallKeep.addEventListener("endCall", onEndCall);

    const callUuid = uuid.v4().toString();

    RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(callUuid, skill, skill);
 } catch(e) {...}
```

Comment: Could you add some code into your question? Specifically, the part that listens for the push notification of the native call.